# Show reset button after counter reaches zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I would like to hide and then show the "Reset" button as soon as the counter reaches zero.

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="timer">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        timer = new Countdown();
        timer.init();
     </script>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#reset").click(function(){
        //timer = new Countdown();  
        timer.reset();
        });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/orokusaki/o4ak8wzs/1/ for countdown.js

Comment: you could try using custom events and event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWolf's answer is a bit fancier than mine, and they made some good points about your code, but I tried to keep mine simple and tried not to change your original code too much.

Your `init()` function will now hide the Reset button, and I had the `update_target()` function show the Reset button when the timer expired.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgutierrez1014/o4ak8wzs/4/

Comment: rgutierrez1014 Perfect! Thanks very much - works a charm

Comment: rgutierrez1014 though sorry to say it seems I'm having trouble with the hide - it does not seem to be hiding the Reset as the page loads?

Comment: @StevieWonder Hmm, it was working in the Fiddle. Well then just paste this line after  `$(document).ready(function(){`: `$("#reset").hide();`. Or see this updated Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rgutierrez1014/o4ak8wzs/5/)

Comment: one more thing - is there an easy way to then hide the Reset button after say 5 seconds of it being shown?

Answer (score 0):

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/o4ak8wzs/2/) you'll find the updated code and how you could add that behaviour.

I've also improved your code a bit. It's easier to write `Countdown.prototype = { init: function() {...}, ...}` then writing `Countdown.prototype.init = function() {...}`

I also changed your `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and start a new timeout every second. That's easier and you don't need to clear the interval at the end. Also the callback function for your interval seemed a bit strange and that probably won't work.

You could add your click handlers in the init method of your countdown object like this `$('#start').click(this.start.bind(this));` the `.bind(this)` is used to change the context inside the click handler to the currently used object. Then this inside of the handler is your object and you can access everything with `this`.

To hide the reset button at start I've used the css `display: none;` and if you are at zero then show the button with `$('#reset').fadeIn('slow');` or `$('#reset').show();` if you don't want the animation.

---

**Update 13.03.2015**

As mentioned in the comments I've improved the code and now I'm using a [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/).

Please have a look at the latest version in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/683oz5Lz/).

I think it's much better then the other code.

```js
(function () {

    function Countdown() {
        this.start_time = "00:30";
        this.target_id = "#timer";
        //this.name = "timer";
    }

    Countdown.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            console.log('init called');
            this.reset();
            $('#start').click(this.start.bind(this));
            $('#reset').click(this.reset.bind(this));
        },
        reset: function () {
            time = this.start_time.split(":");
            //this.minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
            this.seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
            this.update_target();
        },
        tick: function () {
            if (this.seconds > 0) //|| this.minutes > 0)
            {
                if (this.seconds == 0) {
                    // this.minutes = this.minutes - 1;
                    this.seconds = 59
                } else {
                    this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
                }
                this.start();
            }
            else {
                // show reset button
                $('#reset').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            this.update_target();
        },
        start: function() {
            console.log('start called');
            //setTimeout(this.name + '.tick()', 1000);
            setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
        },
        update_target: function () {
            seconds = this.seconds;
            if (seconds < 10) seconds = "" + seconds;
            $(this.target_id).val(this.seconds);
        }
    };

    var counter = new Countdown();
    counter.init();

})();
```

```css
#reset {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="timer">
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: sorry it seems this isn't quite working in my browsers - the time does not appear in the input box either before or after Start is clicked

Comment: I've tested the fiddle with IE11, FF36, Chrome 41 with Windows 8.1 with-out a problem. Do you have the problem in the fiddle or in your script that you're working on?

Comment: just in my script - I've copied and pasted the js into a js file and the html into an html file and included the css in the html file however the 30s does not appear.

Comment: Have you tried to add `new Countdown ()` and `init` in a jQuery DomReady function? It probably runs too early.

Comment: I think i've done that however still not working. Also is there an easy way to hide Reset after a certain time of it being shown e.g. say 10 seconds

Comment: I've changed the code a bit and now I'm using a [jquery countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/). You can find the demo code in this [git repo](https://github.com/AWolf81/countdown-js).

Comment: Click the button multiple times and see what happens ;) You should probably add toggle `disabled` on the start button once it's been clicked. Also, if you enter a value like 60, it still counts down from 30. ALSO, if you hit reset while the counter is running, it doesn't actually reset.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's a bug. :-) Disabling would be OK, also clearing the currently running timeout will work. I've updated the code a bit in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/o4ak8wzs/6/).